# How to use if statement within map in javascript/vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapping, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `Vuejs` where I'm getting a response data and I'm mapping it to a variable, I've got few elements which has empty array, so while mapping I want to check the condition and map accordingly. Here is my code:

```
this.model = a.map(i => Object.assign({
    'id': i.id,
    'meeting_date': i.schedule,
    'meeting_call': i.type,
    'event_type': i.event_type,
    'venue': i.venue,
    'with_client': i.with_client
},{
    if(i.meeting.meeting_summaries)
    {
        'meeting_summaries': i.meeting_summaries.map(ms => ({
            client_name: ms.client_name,
            nature: ms.nature,
            action: ms.action,
            mention: ms.user_id,
            feedback: ms.feedback
        }))
    }

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is purely functional, it doesn't modify the elements instead return a newly formed array, so you can do like this:

```
this.model = a.map(i => {
  var item = {}
  item['id']= i.id,
  item['meeting_date']= i.schedule,
  item['meeting_call']= i.type,
  item['event_type']= i.event_type,
  item['venue']= i.venue,
  item['with_client']= i.with_client
  if(i.meeting && i.meeting.meeting_summaries) {
     item['meeting_summaries']= i.meeting.meeting_summaries.map(ms =>({
            client_name: ms.client_name,
            nature: ms.nature,
            action: ms.action,
            mention: ms.user_id,
            feedback: ms.feedback
        }))
  }else {
   item['meeting_summaries'] = []
  }
 return item
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to declare a variable object and then assign data?, as before placing if statement my code was running as desired.

Comment: You need to declared a new variable, as you are picking some properties but not all from result object, and you have to return it.

Comment: so I'm defining in first line itself as `this.model = a.map(i => Object.assign())`

Comment: Object.assign will expect source and target arguments as object literals, hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yes very well. Thanks.

Comment: @SrinivasDamam this is not true, you can create an object using `Object.assign` with one argument like this: `b = a.map(n => Object.assign({a: n}))`

Comment: He wrote if condition inside the object literal which wrong, There is no issue if you  return objects @wostex

Comment: @SrinivasDamam my comment is about this: `You need to declared a new variable`... You don't.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just swap to [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
this.model = a.map(i => Object.assign({
    'id': i.id,
    'meeting_date': i.schedule,
    'meeting_call': i.type,
    'event_type': i.event_type,
    'venue': i.venue,
    'with_client': i.with_client
}, (i.meeting.meeting_summaries) ? { // if condition is met
    'meeting_summaries': i.meeting_summaries.map(ms => ({
        client_name: ms.client_name,
        nature: ms.nature,
        action: ms.action,
        mention: ms.user_id,
        feedback: ms.feedback
    }))
} : {} // otherwise don't do anything
```

The idea is the following:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const b = a.map(number => Object.assign({a: number}, 
  (number > 2) ? {b: ++number} : {}, // add 'b' for numbers > 2
  (number % 2 === 0) ? {c: number + ' is even'} : {} // add 'c' for even numbers
  ))
  
console.log(b)
```